# How to split app and vendor code with Webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack, vendor

I'm starting a new project with react 
So I have this `webpack.config.js` file that's supposed to hundle 2 chunks , one for the app code and one for vendor based on this exemple from webpack [documentation](https://webpack.github.io/docs/code-splitting.html#split-app-and-vendor-code)

**webpack.config.js**

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        app: './src/App.jsx',
        vendor: ['react', 'react-dom', 'whatwg-fetch']
    },
    output: {
        path: __dirname + './static/',
        filename: 'app.bundle.js'
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: 'vendor',
            filename: 'vendor.bundle.js'
        })
    ],
    module: {
        loaders: [{
            test: /.jsx$/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            query: {
                presets: ['react', 'es2015']
            }
        }, ]
    }
};
```

When I run `webpack -p` I can see that my two assets are supposed to be generated but there is nothing in the output directory.

**Webpack output**

```
           Asset    Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
   app.bundle.js    6 kB       0  [emitted]  app
vendor.bundle.js  108 kB       1  [emitted]  vendor
   [6] ./src/App.jsx 3.37 kB {0} [built]
   [7] ./src/IssueAdd.jsx 3.57 kB {0} [built]
   [9] ./src/IssueList.jsx 5.46 kB {0} [built]
  [10] ./src/IssueFilter.jsx 2.52 kB {0} [built]
  [20] multi react react-dom whatwg-fetch 52 bytes {1} [built]
    + 16 hidden modules
```

Webpack version is 3.8.1 with windows 7 dev environment. 
Am I missing something here?

Comment: which version of webpack are you using ?

Comment: webpack -v gives 3.8.1

Comment: What is you OS? It is possible that the output path is wrong. Try using `path` module from Node with `resolve`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want two separate files to be emitted in output folder Firstly you have to make sure those files have new name every-time files are updated and one of the ways is to make use of caching [chunkhash] as suggested in webpack 3.8.1 [Documentation](https://webpack.js.org/guides/caching/)

Include path on top of the file , so your output should be something like (You can change it accordingly):

```
 var path = require('path');

 output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: '[name].[chunkhash].js'
  },
```

And inside your plugin you can just give name

```
plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: 'vendor'
    }) 
]
```

You can read more about Webpack [3.8.1 output-filename](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#output-filename)

Comment: Thanks solved .. just one more question why should I use a hash in the file name ?

Comment: which hash ? are you talking about [`chunkhash`] ?

Comment: yes .. never mind I've read the doc for chunkhash and it's pretty clear .. thanks again :)

Comment: Glad to help you out :)